# getting ID of HTML <source>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am trying to load in the source of videos and sound files on my website from JSON files. I do this for other elements on my page using:

```
`$('#cimg').attr('src', jsonObj.cloud[0].refimage)`
```

This seems to work for things like images, but not for HTML 5 video and sound files where there is source tags like so:

```
<source id="cvid" src="" type="video/mp4">
```

I think that you can't create ID's in source tags, because the same method works for img tags.

Does anyone know how I can give or access the id from a source tag?

Answer (score 2):

You could just grab the tag:

```
console.log($('source').attr('id'))
```

[JSFiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/cu7tn64o/5/)

Comment: im not sure how you mean. I need to grab it in the `$('#cimg').attr section

Comment: also I have more than one source tag, so that way would not work

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `<source>` element like any other element, be it by `id`.

What you did forget however, is that when you modify its `src` attribute, you have to call the `.load()` method of its container `<video>` element.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('vid');
var source = document.getElementById('cvid');
var src = ['http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4', 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4'];
var s = 0;

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
  
  // change the <source> 's src
  cvid.src = src[++s%src.length];
  // ask the <video> to load this new source
  vid.load();

  // could also be 
  // cvid.parentNode.load();
  
  }
```

```html
<button id="btn">switch video source</button><br>
<video controls muted autoplay id="vid">
<source id="cvid" src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```